# here::here Pulls from Incorrect Directory and Ignores .here File in R

Tags: r

I am having trouble loading my .csv files with here::here.

The here package is setting its default directory as:
    `'Z:/PSE/Analysis/One'`

My working directory is:
`Z:/PSE` and I have put a .here file in that directory.  Here is the message I get after using dr_here():

Here() starts at Z:/PSE/Analysis/One, because it contains a file matching `[.]Rproj$` with contents matching `^Version:` in the first line

I thought the here function started at the current working directory, which is `Z:/PSE`, in which it should recognize the .here file and follow the path that I specify in the remainder of the here function?

Comment: Something about your description seems impossible. Can you present a reprex of actual code using commands `getwd()`, `library(here)`, and `here()`?

Comment: The here package can never go down into the folder hierarchy, it can only go up. So I don't think what you say is possible: that the working directory is `Z:/PSE` and `here::here()` is anchored at `Z:/PSE/Analysis/One`. Note, however, that here determines it's anchor directory at attach time, not call time, so perhaps you made your `library(here)` call and then changed working directory?

Comment: Hi @jennybryan. I did have this problem, but having renamed a xx.Rproj file it has changed - tl;dr here still doesn't identify the directory. Any assistance greatly appreciated. Is this a reproducible workflow? https://gist.github.com/geotheory/bf27a813929d0622a1acbfc8c2e93972